# Having problems loading .properties file

Tags: java, android

I have a common library project shared between a couple of different Android apps that I need to allow for development and production values to be available.  Using Ant I was hoping to be able to swap a environment.properties file for either a dev.properties or prod.properties file.

I am getting a NullPointer exception when trying to load the "/com/iis/..." properties file.

Any ideas to what is being done wrong?

** common is the project

```
static {
    Properties p = new Properties();
    InputStream input = BaseWebApi.class.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/iis/common/environment.properties");
    try {
        p.load(input);
        input.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Unable to load environment.properties file");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    sApiUserName = p.getProperty(KEY_API_USER_NAME);
    sApiPassword = p.getProperty(KEY_API_PASSWORD);
    sServerAddress = p.getProperty(KEY_SERVER_ADDRESS);
    sServerProtocol = p.getProperty(KEY_SERVER_PROTOCOL);
    sServerRootPath = p.getProperty(KEY_SERVER_ROOT_PATH);
    sServerPort = Integer.parseInt(p.getProperty(KEY_SERVER_PORT));
}
```

** not to much to see in the stacktrace

```
09-09 12:35:43.935: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(853): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-09 12:35:43.935: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(853):     at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:290)
09-09 12:35:43.935: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(853):     at com.iis.common.webapis.BaseWebApi.<clinit>(BaseWebApi.java:60)
09-09 12:35:43.935: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(853):     ... 8 more
```

*** I have tried every possible name combo that I can think of using the namespaces, folders and classnames

```
// namespaces, folder
"/com/iis/android_common/environment.properties"
"com/iis/android_common/environment.properties"

// namespaces, project name
"/com/iis/common/environment.properties"
"com/iis/common/environment.properties"

// folder
"/android_common/environment.properties"

// project name
"/common/environment.properties"

// direct path
/environment.properties
environment.properties
```

Comment: maybe try removing the first / in the file path "com/iis/common/environment.properties"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you certain your resources are being packaged in the dex file? See http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10076.

Comment: Ah they were not.  For clarification if you run `jar tvf your_project_name.apk | grep .properties` you can determine if the properties file you are trying to include do indeed exist.  After moving the properties files to the assets folder they were then included in the apk.

Answer (score 0):

Just an additional note in regards to the path required to access the file and other issue fixes.

The code below works in accessing 'your_project_path/assets/api.properties`

```
public class WebApi {
    private static final String TAG = "WebApi";

    // configuration keys
    private static final String API_URL = "api_url";
    private static final String API_PROTOCOL = "api_protocol";
    private static final String API_PORT = "api_port";

    // server settings
    protected static String URL;
    protected static String PROTOCOL;
    protected static int PORT;

    // load server dev/prod settings via api.properties file
    static {
        InputStream input = WebApi.class.getResourceAsStream("/assets/api.properties");
        Properties p = new Properties();
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "Setting api properties");
            p.load(input);

            URL = p.getProperty(API_URL);
            PROTOCOL = p.getProperty(API_PROTOCOL);
            PORT = Integer.parseInt(p.getProperty(API_PORT));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    #...
}
```

One other thing to note the previously used keys to access the properties must be lower case (they were not in the initial posting, although I didn't post the properties file contents).

```
// api.properties (don't use upper case)
api_url=10.0.1.7
api_protocol=http
api_port=3000
```

Hopefully that will clear things up a little more for anyone else that has this problem.